# PHP elseif statement inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Hello there I have a php foreach loop running that is all working except one part.  I am pulling in data from a local json file.  The beginning foreach call looks like this:

```
<?php foreach($boatslips as $boatslip): ?>
```

One of the json fields is:  "rent_sale_or_both" : "rent"   (but that field can be rent, sale, or both,)

Lower down in the code after some other fields are successfully rendered and inside the foreach loop still i'm trying the below code to render out whether a boat slip is for rent, sale or both; and wanting to then be able to style 'rent' 'sale' or 'both' with css eventually.

```
<?php 
if ($boatslip->rent_sale_or_both == rent) {
   echo "rent";
}elseif ($boatslip->rent_sale_or_both == sale) {
   echo "sale";
}else  {
   echo "both";
}
?>
```

Then some more html after the elseif.

At the end of the for each loop it is closed off properly with `<?php endforeach; ?>`

Obviously this is probably not correct? I think I'm making it harder than it is?
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is it not correct, do you think? Is a specific problem occurring? Or are you just thinking there might be a more succinct way of writing the same logic? Please clarify your exact question.

Comment: You want to compare the value to a string, so you need quotes around the comparison value `$boatslip->rent_sale_or_both == 'rent'`. But if you're just outputting the same value that you're comparing to, you can just echo that instead, and get rid of the conditional altogether `echo $boatslip->rent_sale_or_both;`.

Comment: Have you tried using ternary syntax?

Comment: It's because you're missing an apostrophe or two. In `$boat'slips`. No seriously though, turn on your error reporting and it will be obvious where the problem is.

Comment: I did have my error reporting on.... ;-) Just didn't read it very well.  I'm not a php expert i;m sorry.  I'm interested though for learning purposes how might it look using the Ternary?  I also thought of doing it with a Switch statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a couple of quotation marks.

$boatslip->rent_sale_or_both == "rent"

$boatslip->rent_sale_or_both == "sale"

Comment: Thank you I just missed that!  Very tired!  Works now ;)